# HTML::FormHandler field validation based on other field's check'd state

Tags: perl, catalyst, html-formhandler

I am developing a Perl/Catalyst web app using HTML::FormHandler for forms.
I am trying to do a conditional validation on a field if a checkbox is checked.

The code below is from a Role I created for my form to use.

```
has_field 'autosys_jobs.schedule.has_run_day_of_month' => ( type=>'Boolean');
has_field 'autosys_jobs.schedule.run_day_of_month' => ( type => 'PosInteger');

#Validation function for 'autosys_jobs.schedule.run_day_of_month'
sub validate_autosys_jobs_schedule_run_day_of_month {
    my ( $self, $field ) = @_;
    if( $self->field('autosys_jobs.schedule.has_run_day_of_month')->value ) {
       #validate 'autosys_jobs.schedule.run_day_of_month'
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that `$self->field('autosys_jobs.schedule.has_run_day_of_month')->value` 
for the boolean field always returns 0 even if it's checked.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: is the validate function being called? Because field ( type => 'boolean' ) does exactly what you want for me, I am currently using that without problems - i.e. for me, checkbox checked => field->value is true. 

I am asking because HTML::Formhandler will automatically use field_$fieldname subs for validation, but it is called 'validate_autosys_jobs_schedule_run_day_of_month', whereas your field is 'autosys_jobs.schedule.has_run_day_of_month' ( note the dots )

Comment: Yes the validate function is being called. I confirmed this also the documentation directs to rename any dots with an underscore.

Comment: did not know that. Seemed like the only thing that could have been wrong, but I am glad to see it wasn't and you have figured it out yourself. Perhaps you should mention all relevant info next time ;)

Answer (score 0):

After digging deeper into the HTML::FormHandler documentation I was able to figure out my mistake.
The field autosys_jobs.schedule is a compound field(forgot to mention that)

```
has_field 'autosys_jobs.schedule' => ( type => 'Compound');
```

in order to access the field of interest I had to use the following in my validate sub:

```
$self->field('autosys_jobs.0.schedule.has_run_day_of_month')->value
```

Thanks all